# how to Remove object and filling with Background if i have pixel locations

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb, picturefill

IF i have pixel location for abject as [x, y] = find(Bw2 == 0);
then how i remove it then filling with Original background

this my code

```
[x, y] = find(Bw2 == 0);
[row, colo, z]=size(RGB); %size of rgb image
for i=1:row
    for j=1:colo
        if any(i==x)    %if the row of rgb image is the same of pixel location row
            if any(j==y(i==x)) %if the colos of rgb image is the same of pixel loca colo

     Free_image= imfill(RGB,i,j);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that Bw2 is a binary mask of the same size as RGB (without the 3rd dimension).  I am also guessing you want to replace all pixels in RGB with a fixed background color if the corresponding pixel in Bw2 is zero.

If so, you can do this:

```
bg_color = [0.5 0.5 0.5];  % this is gray, but can be changed to anything
sz = size(RGB);
numPix = sz(1) * sz(2);
indx = find(Bw2 == 0);
RGB(indx)            = bg_color(1);
RGB(indx + numPix)   = bg_color(2);
RGB(indx + numPix*2) = bg_color(3);
```